# Blender 3.4+: How to pose a character and move bones without getting a single keyframe error?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, pose-mode

How to move bones and pose a character without all sorts of keyframe errors? I would like to animate a character from OBJ file or eventually make 3D images.

Have figured out how to make a bone (via manual, Shift+A > Armature > Bone) and rigged the character, only need to pose a character. This is the first time [on Blender] and have zero experience on rigging anything 3D.

I want to **rig a character for pictures or videos rendering**. Needing one character ready for a beautiful picture/video, so I have created one, tried to rig it:
[image: A voxel character rigged.]

There is an error when trying to pose, hinting on the requirement of keyframes.
[image: Zero keyframes to slide between.]

There is an official way to do keyframes here, but that's hard to be dealt with. Cutting the entire character into lesser bones would be also impossible since the character would be welding props (e.g., a gun.)

How to do it, or do Blender 3.x+ turned out impossible for newbies to pose a character?

**UPDATE A01:** @Blunder send me a suggestion, stating that people are tend to go to Pose Mode, select a bone, do transformation -- rotate, move, etc. I to create a keyframe, through. This resulted in character get a fatal move:

[image]

[note: there's 16 armatures on that file.]

Comment: Hello and welcome. To give you a satisfactory answer, we need a few basic details. All we know from your text is that you're new to Blender, rigged a model (or at least tried to), and ran into this "no keyframes" error when you tried to create a pose or keyframe. It's not clear what you have done. Describe what you have tried and what you want to achieve. Add a screenshot. For a simple pose, you don't need keyframes at all. You need them for animation. That's at least 2 poses and a few keyframes at 2 different frames.

Comment: I would suggest cutting the problem down to an absolute minimum, playing with just one or two bones in an armature, on their own. Try key-framing those, and if you get stuck,  come back with that very specific problem. Then folks will find it much easier to help you out.

Comment: @RobinBetts: How to keyframe it? That's stuck already since Blender v3.4+!

Comment: @blunder: Rigged a model for rendering use, photo and video. I want to pose one for a photo/video 3D render, 1920x1080 (system's native res) ~ 4K. I have created a character from MagicaVoxel, exported into a *.OBJ file. Gimme a second for including a screenshot.

Comment: [@RobinBetts updated rep from me:] Cannot abide to play with only one or two bone on an armature. If do it, that should've harder for welding props (especially, guns, cellphones, handheld props, etc.) Even make hard [final] renders crappier.

Comment: Hi @pphu15 !   I'm not suggesting you abandon anything .. far from it ! .. Just trying to isolate your problem. If you _can_ pose a couple of bones, but _can't_ pose your rig, then it might help figure out what's up. If you can't pose a couple of bones, then our search-space is much smaller.. :) Feel free to share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I still don't know how you got this error. Are you using the *Pose Library*? How many armatures are there? (in the screenshot there is *Armature.005*). Usually, you select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, select a bone, do the transformation (rotate, move, scale), and then press the I key to create a keyframe. That's it. -- If I search for the error message "No keyframes to slide between" there are only a few matches, including this question. The others seem to be source code files of Blender (pose_slide.c).

Comment: Have you pressed Shift+E in *Pose* mode or used the menu *Pose > In-Betweens > ...*? This produces the error "No keyframes to slide between" when there are no keyframes.

Comment: @Blunder Will revise. Seconds left, here we go.

Comment: @RobinBetts I may go thru a 3D modeling school while there was an abandoned standard school path since I was 13. File sharing is not good, I couldn't cost all the way to study how to rig and make a character only to get mod's assistance....

Comment: @Blunder The entire character moves... but that wasn't a proper move. Don't want a bad pose. Revision incoming.

Comment: You say yourself you have no experience in this, yet you are already trying to rig and animate a full character. In that regard, I join @RobinBetts on suggesting you to learn how to walk before attempting a marathon. It looks like helping you would require to post a lengthy answer that would look more like an anthology of rephrased manual pages than a simple answer to a single question, which sounds out of context for this Q&A site. So, maybe find a tutorial somewhere that explains how to rig and animate, and practice it on something simple. Once you can do that, then move to a full character.

Comment: It looks like you have created 1 armature for each bone. That's not correct. You only need 1 armature that has all bones in it. You can try to join (Ctrl+J) all armature objects into one. After you have created the armature you need to bind the mesh (Ctrl+P) and do some weight painting if needed. Check out this [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL3OEv6vd5VCrqZiupP2m68qSWHYAjoiW) to learn about armatures, deformation and control bones, and FK/IK.

Comment: There's no idea 'bout this. Thanks. I thought Shift+A > Armature > Bone would add only one bone but the armature. Sorry about that. @Blunder - I never knew about that.